# rsync leads to almost all corrupted files

Tags: rsync

I copied files from one server to another with rsync 3.0.6 on CentOS 6:

```
rsync --exclude=".bash*" --progress --verbose -lpogtzr /home/ 1.2.3.4:/home/
```

but many synced files have different checksum on the destination server. I copied again files (sometimes with z flag, sometimes without it) and now all seems ok.

HDDs are ok. Services was active in the old server when I made the first copy. Later I stopped services on both servers before starting another rsync to copy only differences in a faster way. I always made a dry-run before.

How it may be happened? Shouldn't be rsync a stable program?

Comment: The problem is terrible. Actually we switched back to the old server because it was impossible to copy files. We requested an hardware check to the farm and they told us all is ok

Comment: Do the files with different checksums have the same content? How do the checksums differ? Show us some examples (actual output of `ls -l`).

Comment: The resulting files on the destination server are corrupted, so no, the content is not the same.

Comment: I checked checksums with md5sum

Comment: Shouldn't the subsequent rsyncs have checked and copied all differences? Or the -a and -t flag causes troubles?

Comment: The rsync command should have copied all files the first time. Which is why, to understand why it didn't, we need more information. Just comparing checksums doesn't give much information. Do the files have the same metadata? Is the target a truncation of the original? Was there some reencoding? etc. We can't help you if you don't provide some sample information.

Comment: metadata are the same. Files are SQLite databases but I cannot determine what is happened inside

Comment: Were these SQLite databases in use when you copied them? `rsync` doesn't lock files during transfer.

Comment: For those others wondering, `-lpogtzr` is equivalent to `-a --no-D`, although I suspect that `-a` would be quite acceptable here (and easier to understand)

Comment: Yes, they were open by a SQLite daemon.

Comment: You should either shutdown the sqlite daemon temporarily while rsyncing the databases, or dump the databases to a text file and backup that.  The rsynced copies are most likely corrupted because the db changed while it was being rsynced.

Comment: Ok. But why, when I stopped services and did a second rsync, the rsync delta algorithm didn't update the broken parts?

Comment: Also in a Bare Metal backup context, how I can manage SQLite files? No commercial Bare Metal Backup tool support agents for SQLite DBs or shuts down the daemon...

Answer (score 1):

I think I've understood what is happened. I made the first rsync when services was active so resulting files was corrupted (this is ok).

Then I stopped services and I did a second rsync to copy only differences in a faster way.

This didn't worked. Maybe the -t flag is the culprit? Maybe the mtime of files is not updated every time you write a byte but only when you open a file for writing?

Comment: The `-t` flag uses the granularity of the filesystems. This can cause problems if the source and destination have different granularity, by the way; in such cases use `--modify-window` to add a tolerance.

Comment: destination is ext3, source ext4. In my case --modify-window does the opposite